# Office 2016 app language changed to Russian

Tags: microsoft-office, language

I always kept getting these notifications from Get Office application titled "Try Office 365 for 1 month"  It didn't bother me much. However today I've got the same notification but in Russian. I opened up the Get Office app and it was completely in Russian whilst using English before.

My system language/locale is set to UK/US.

Why did it switch to Russian for no reason?

[image]

Comment: Your question is why did the nagware popup change to Russian?

Comment: Not only the nagware popup but the app itself.

Comment: But the Russian is limited to the Get Office utility, not the Office application?  Are you using Office 2016 (in English), and everything else on the system is in English, so only that utility is in Russian?

Comment: That is right, Get Office utility is in Russian. I don't use Office 2016. Every other app is in English. In fact, the entire system is English

Comment: Actually I remember changing the language for non-unicode programs to Russian once. I needed it for one program. However, I've changed it back to UK English about a week ago but the nagware popup and the app is still in Russian. I dont know if this is related because Get Office is supposedly unicode-supported?